# How to add spherical texture to canvas arc

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

How can I add spherical texture like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojwD8.jpg) to `HTML` `canvas` **circle** (arc) with **2d** context to get fake ***3d*** sphere.

I've tried `clip`, `fillStyle` and various other methods to draw that image in arc. But all of them got flat look. I think I need to map spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates.

I'm currently using following **code** to draw arc and the image.

```js
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2)
ctx.closePath()
ctx.clip()
ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy)
```

I expect the output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rinc.png)

EDIT: I can't use CSS or any other 3rd party libraries. I need to use pure JavaScript and canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create pure CSS 3-dimensional spheres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238194/how-can-i-create-pure-css-3-dimensional-spheres)