# merge pure CSS 3-dimensional spheres in svg code

Tags: html, css, svg

1- the first code is svg circle that i add to rotation function (i learn about animation, keyframs from stackoverflow from another Q). and mold it in to html body.

```html
<html>
<body>
<svg width="100" height="100">
<defs>   
<style id="style20"> #test {animation: wheel 4s infinite linear;transform-origin: center;transform-box: fill-box;} @keyframes wheel { from { transform: rotatex(360deg); } to { transform: rotatey(0deg);}}</style>
</defs>

<circle id="test" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="black" />
</svg> 
 
</body>
</html>
```

2- the next code is from answer on another question under subject of "How can I create pure CSS 3-dimensional spheres?"
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238194/how-can-i-create-pure-css-3-dimensional-spheres][1]

```css
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 98vmin;
  height: 98vmin;
  margin: 1vmin;  
  transform-style: preserve-3d;  
  transform: rotateX(-5deg);
}

@keyframes rot{
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg); }
}

.layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 98vmin;
  height: 98vmin;
}

.moving
{
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 49vmin 49vmin;
  animation: rot 10s linear infinite;
}






.clip
{
  border-radius: 50%;  
  overflow:hidden;
  transform: translateZ(-0vmin);
}

     
 @keyframes highlightanim {     
  0.00% {left: -150.00%; top: -178.00% }
  12.50% {left: -117.67%; top: -179.64% }
  25.00% {left: -97.69%; top: -195.87% }
  28.75% {left: -95.00%; top: -207.09% }
  32.50% {left: -97.69%; top: -220.70% }
  40.00% {left: -117.67%; top: -240.01% }
  47.50% {left: -150.00%; top: -247.50% }
  55.00% {left: -182.33%; top: -240.01% }
  62.50% {left: -202.31%; top: -220.70% }
  68.75% {left: -205.00%; top: -207.09% }
  75.00% {left: -202.31%; top: -195.87% }
  87.50% {left: -182.33%; top: -179.64% }
  100.00% {left: -150.00%; top: -178.00% }
} 
  
.shade
{
  position: relative;
  top: -150%;
  left: -150%;
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;
  background: radial-gradient(at 50% 50%, white, black, grey, black, black);
  animation: highlightanim 10s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball">
  <div class='layer moving'>
     
    <div class='layer gridplane laser'></div>  
    <div class='layer gridplane laser2'></div>  
  </div> 
  <div class='layer clip'>
    <div class='shade'> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

3- how can put the second code in the same mold as first code (inside body of html, divided to functions and path that effected by the functions?

4- i try edit the value of x, y and z in the code to make it look like rotate around X axis (from down of page to up of it, same direction like the first code), but without any effect. is there's way to do that?

5- the color, i try change value of

thanks for advance

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Do you want an SVG version of the second (HTML) example?

Comment: yes svg version from the scond code "3-d spheres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG equivalent of your HTML is the following:

```css
.shade
{
  animation: highlightanim 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes highlightanim {     
  0.00% {x: -150.00; y: -178.00 }
  12.50% {x: -117.67; y: -179.64 }
  25.00% {x: -97.69; y: -195.87 }
  28.75% {x: -95.00; y: -207.09 }
  32.50% {x: -97.69; y: -220.70 }
  40.00% {x: -117.67; y: -240.01 }
  47.50% {x: -150.00; y: -247.50 }
  55.00% {x: -182.33; y: -240.01 }
  62.50% {x: -202.31; y: -220.70 }
  68.75% {x: -205.00; y: -207.09 }
  75.00% {x: -202.31; y: -195.87 }
  87.50% {x: -182.33; y: -179.64 }
  100.00% {x: -150.00; y: -178.00 }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="500">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="shade-gradient"
      cx="50%" cy="50%" r="70.7%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="grey"/>
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"/>
    </radialGradient>
    
    <clipPath id="layer-clip">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <rect class="shade" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400"
        fill="url(#shade-gradient)" clip-path="url(#layer-clip)"/>
</svg>
```

**Request: Rotate from down to up**

The simplest way to do that is to rotate the SVG 90 degrees.

However I don't think the effect works as good.

```css
svg
{
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.shade
{
  animation: highlightanim 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes highlightanim {     
  0.00% {x: -150.00; y: -178.00 }
  12.50% {x: -117.67; y: -179.64 }
  25.00% {x: -97.69; y: -195.87 }
  28.75% {x: -95.00; y: -207.09 }
  32.50% {x: -97.69; y: -220.70 }
  40.00% {x: -117.67; y: -240.01 }
  47.50% {x: -150.00; y: -247.50 }
  55.00% {x: -182.33; y: -240.01 }
  62.50% {x: -202.31; y: -220.70 }
  68.75% {x: -205.00; y: -207.09 }
  75.00% {x: -202.31; y: -195.87 }
  87.50% {x: -182.33; y: -179.64 }
  100.00% {x: -150.00; y: -178.00 }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="500">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="shade-gradient"
      cx="50%" cy="50%" r="70.7%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="grey"/>
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"/>
    </radialGradient>
    
    <clipPath id="layer-clip">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <rect class="shade" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400"
        fill="url(#shade-gradient)" clip-path="url(#layer-clip)"/>
</svg>
```

**Request: Change the colour**

Just change the colours in the gradient.

```css
svg
{
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.shade
{
  animation: highlightanim 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes highlightanim {     
  0.00% {x: -150.00; y: -178.00 }
  12.50% {x: -117.67; y: -179.64 }
  25.00% {x: -97.69; y: -195.87 }
  28.75% {x: -95.00; y: -207.09 }
  32.50% {x: -97.69; y: -220.70 }
  40.00% {x: -117.67; y: -240.01 }
  47.50% {x: -150.00; y: -247.50 }
  55.00% {x: -182.33; y: -240.01 }
  62.50% {x: -202.31; y: -220.70 }
  68.75% {x: -205.00; y: -207.09 }
  75.00% {x: -202.31; y: -195.87 }
  87.50% {x: -182.33; y: -179.64 }
  100.00% {x: -150.00; y: -178.00 }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="500">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="shade-gradient"
      cx="50%" cy="50%" r="70.7%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ff8080"/>
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
    </radialGradient>
    
    <clipPath id="layer-clip">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <rect class="shade" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400"
        fill="url(#shade-gradient)" clip-path="url(#layer-clip)"/>
</svg>
```

**Backwards compatible version**

In the above examples, I've relied on being able to style geometry attributes with CSS. In this case `x` and `y` in the animation.

Styling geometry attributes is a relatively new thing that not all browsers support yet.  So I've added a more backwards-compatible version below.

```css
svg
{
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.shade
{
  animation: highlightanim 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes highlightanim {     
  0.00% { transform: translate(-150.00px, -178.00px); }
  12.50% { transform: translate(-117.67px, -179.64px); }
  25.00% { transform: translate(-97.69px, -195.87px); }
  28.75% { transform: translate(-95.00px, -207.09px); }
  32.50% { transform: translate(-97.69px, -220.70px); }
  40.00% { transform: translate(-117.67px, -240.01px); }
  47.50% { transform: translate(-150.00px, -247.50px); }
  55.00% { transform: translate(-182.33px, -240.01px); }
  62.50% { transform: translate(-202.31px, -220.70px); }
  68.75% { transform: translate(-205.00px, -207.09px); }
  75.00% { transform: translate(-202.31px, -195.87px); }
  87.50% { transform: translate(-182.33px, -179.64px); }
  100.00% { transform: translate(-150.00px, -178.00px); }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="500">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="shade-gradient"
      cx="50%" cy="50%" r="70.7%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ff8080"/>
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
    </radialGradient>
    
    <clipPath id="layer-clip">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <g clip-path="url(#layer-clip)">
    <rect class="shade" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400"
          fill="url(#shade-gradient)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: many thanks for you. really appropriate your efforts.
 but when see the results using "run code snippet", it give only the shape without the animation(no movement appears, just fixed image). is there's some way to make the blur white color infinite movement from side to other, so look like 3D ball movement?

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox.
when click on "Run code snippet" it show the circle and the whit part(that give movement effect when change his place) over it, but the whit part stay fixed without any move. i also try run the code on https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_myfirst but did not work. i will install chrome and try from it.

Comment: Okay.  Apologies.  I've added a new version to my answer that works in Firefox.

Comment: it work, many thanks.

Comment: your notice about "geometry attributes with CSS" and "browsers support", make me see that "stack-overflow not support run the code on it, but it like a bridge that help(or direct) the user browser to run the code for show the results".